# allowing user to export react web page as pdf

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How do I allow users to export a customized react web page as pdf, image or share it using gmail.
I created a template for a CV with editable components, and I'm trying to find a way for the user to export them as they are, so using jsPDF is not suitable.

Answer (score 1):

You can ue html2canvas for converting your page to a canvas then you can conver the canvas to pdf or img.Advantage of using html2canvas is you won't miss any styles applied to the content.

here is a sample for generating img.

```
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
GetImg() {
    html2canvas(document.querySelector("#root")).then(canvas => {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL()
      saveAs(img, "pretty image.png");
    });
  }
```

for pdf you can use jspdf along with html2canvas . here is a sample

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
getPdf(){
input= document.querySelector("#root")
html2canvas(input)
      .then((canvas) => {
        const imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        const pdf = new jsPDF({
          orientation: 'landscape',
        });
        const imgProps= pdf.getImageProperties(imgData);
        const pdfWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.getWidth();
        const pdfHeight = (imgProps.height * pdfWidth) / imgProps.width;
        pdf.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 0, 0, pdfWidth, pdfHeight);
        pdf.save('download.pdf');
      });}
```

Comment: class Result5 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
          <img src={locationlogo} className="smallimage" />
          <h2 contentEditable="true">Adreess</h2>
      </div>

    );
  }
}
export default Result5;I'm using this as a test (it's for the address of the user) where do I add the canvas ?

Comment: You can import jspdf,html2canvas,filesaver in your component. Then add getimg and getpdf file to your component. Attach this function as an event handler to your components any of the elements

Answer (score 0):

So basically you need to convert HTML and CSS into a pdf. Javascript doesn't have anything to do with the pdf, and React is javascript, so we need to extract the HTML actually.

What you could do is keep a ref on the wrapper element that wraps the CV, then do a `ref.current.innerHTML` to get the HTML code of your CV. Also get your CSS, and use jsPDF to convert the HTML and the CSS into a pdf.